# Android ListView to next activity ListView

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, listactivity

i have problem with my android app, i searched but cannot find answer, i have this code:

```
public class Matematika extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  

      String[] mStrings = new String[]{"Mother", "Sister", "Brother"};

      // Create an ArrayAdapter, that will actually make the Strings above appear in the ListView
      this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
      android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mStrings));
  }
}
```

And i want to make for example this: I want to click on Mother and want to go next ListActivity (new activity via intent if is it real), ListActivity, where is another options....

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(lv, v, position, id);
        try {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:  //Mother
                    //Launch MotherActivity
                    Intent motherIntent = new Intent(this, MotherListActivity.class);
                    startActivity(motherIntent);
                break;
            case 1:  //Sister
                //Call SisterActivity
                Intent sisterIntent = new Intent(this, SisterListActivity.class);
                startActivity(sisterIntent);
                break;
            case 2:  //Brother
                Intent brotherIntent = new Intent(this, BrotherListActivity.class);
                startActivity(eventsIntent);
                break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```